# Batch Render an Animation of One Scene with Multiple Labels?

Tags: texturing, export, image, uv-image-editor, image-sequence

*Background:* I work as a product and brand designer, I would love to be able to export .png's for things with labels- bottles/packaging in general, but I don't want to have to sit at my computer and wait for each one to finish and plug in a new label. Basically anything where the it's the same shape of packaging with different graphics/products inside.

For example, if I wanted to render the exact same environment scene with 50 different images in a picture frame, could I, in theory, have a folder of the correctly proportioned images that feeds into the program and runs one .png after another?

Then I could walk away and come back to my computer having output all the designs and I don't need to check on it every 15 minutes to put in a new artwork.

If y'all come up with anything I'd really appreciate it, cuz the number of items is closer to 500 and this is a daunting task ahead of me.

**Thanks!!**

Comment: If you just want to replace 1 image each frame, I'd suggest an image sequence, where each frame it's another image. If you want to be more complex, I'm afraid you won't get around a littlle scripting.

Comment: +1 to @FrederikSteinmetz ... Great solution  :) Adam, just select all 500 images rename them as 0001.png, 0002.png, ... and use as Texture > Image Sequence. Blender will think it is animated texture and will use each png per frame. Render as Animation Render.